# Can I use std::generate to get a vector of std::array<T, 2>?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

It's easy to use `std::generate` to get a sequence of T. Simple Example code here:

```
std::vector<int> v(5);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [n = 0] () mutable { return n++; });
```

Can I use `std::generate` to get `std::vector<std::array<T,2>>`?

My template function code here:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::array<T, 2>> m(int rows, int cols) {
    std::vector<std::array<T, 2>> vec(rows*cols);
    // this is the x value I want to generate
    std::vector<T> x(rows*cols);
    std::generate(x.begin(), x.end(), 
                  [n = -1, COLS = cols]() mutable { ++n; return n % COLS;});
    // This is the y value I want to generate
    std::vector<T> y(rows*cols);
    std::generate(y.begin(), y.end(), 
         [n = -1, ROWS = rows]() mutable { ++n;  return floor(n / ROWS); });
    // Is it possible to combine the above steps into one step? 
    std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
    [n = -1, COLS = cols, ROWS = rows]() mutable { ++n;  return .... });
    return vec;
}
```

I'd like to combine two steps into one step, is it any convenient way doing so?

Comment: You just have to create an array at the return place, what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lambda should be

```
[n = -1, COLS = cols, ROWS = rows]() mutable {
    ++n;
    return std::array<T, 2>{n % COLS, n / ROWS};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return an `std::array<T, 2>` from your lambda

```
[n = -1, rows, cols]() mutable -> std::array<T, 2> { ++n; return { n % cols, n / rows }; }
```

Comment: This will need an explicit `std::array` somewhere, or that brace-init-list won't ever get a type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have rows and cols dynamically generated as array[0] and array[1] then try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int rows = 5, cols = 3;
    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> vec(rows * cols);

    std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [n = int(-1), cols]() mutable 
    {
        ++n;
        return std::array<int, 2>{n % cols, n / cols}; 
    });

    // test
    std::cout << "COL\tROW" << std::endl;
    for (auto const &arr : vec)
        std::cout << arr[0] << "\t" << arr[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
COL     ROW
0       0
1       0
2       0
0       1
1       1
2       1
0       2
1       2
2       2
0       3
1       3
2       3
0       4
1       4
2       4
```